# Usage of the combination "in immaturity"

Tags: word-usage

My friend was telling me an old story. He used the following lines:

> There were two childhood friends, Drupad and Dron. They studied in the same school. Drupad was a prince and Dron was a son of a peasant. Once Drupad promised Dron that when he would become a king, he would give Dron half of his kingdom. So when Drupad became a king, Dron asked Drupad to give him half of the kingdom as Drupad had promised. On this, Drupad replied that **he had given that promise in immaturity.**

By the sentence **he had given that promise in immaturity**, he meant that **he had given that promise due to his immaturity.**

This combination **in immaturity** looks somewhat weird. Is it a natural way of using this word? Is there a better replacement for this word such as **in naivety**?

Comment: Well, it could be OK: to give a promise in love, to give a promise in all truthfulness, etc. He gave that promise because he was immature.

Comment: The cited text doesn't necessarily have to imply ***due to / because of** his immaturity* - that's just a contextual inference (because the speaker wants to renege on his promise, so he's trying to "undermine" his earlier commitment). All it *actually* specifies is that he made the promise ***when** he was immature* (i.e. ***in*** = ***during** [the immature phase of his life]*). But it's unusual / dated / poetic phrasing, which you wouldn't be likely to use in normal speech today.

Comment: Compare *He gave his promise [**in hopes / hope / the hope of**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+hopes+of+saving%22) saving their lives.* It's really just a matter of "how you see it" as to whether ***in*** there introduces the ***reason*** he gave his promise, or his ***condition, state of mind*** when he did it.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers So, I think we can also use "in childishness/juvenility" here because that is again a state of mind.

Answer (score 2):

It is not ungrammatical but neither is it natural, in 2018, to say "in immaturity" in that particular context, where a person is speaking of his youth.

The phrase **in immaturity** is normally used nowadays to refer to a phase of development of creatures as studied by a biologist or zoologist or physiologist or psychologist.  The phrase is in a scientific register.

> Many readers of the Bulletin are doubtless familiar with a phase of
>   plumage of *Zonotrichia albicollis*, occurring in spring, which
>   appears to be the normal dress of this species in immaturity...

But just a slight change would make it more natural, if still a bit stilted:  **in my immaturity**.